# Force stop in creating circular bitmap

Tags: android, url, bitmap

I'm trying to set circular bitmap by a URL that I got from the server to an ImageView but I'm getting Force Stop SOMETIMES so here is my class for async circular image loading:

```
public class AsyncTaskLoadImage  extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
private final static String TAG = "AsyncTaskLoadImage";
private ImageView imageView;
public AsyncTaskLoadImage(ImageView imageView) {
  this.imageView = imageView;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
  Bitmap bitmap = null;
  try {
    URL url = new URL(params[0]);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 8;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)url.getContent(), null, options);

  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
  }
  return bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
  Bitmap circleBitmap = null;
  circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
  BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader (bitmap,  Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setShader(shader);
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
  c.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2, bitmap.getWidth()/2, paint);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
}
}
```

here is my logcat :

```
10-27 13:43:07.482 19717-19717/com.morlunk.mumbleclient.free E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.morlunk.mumbleclient.free, PID: 19717
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.morlunk.mumbleclient.app.SearchListAdapter$AsyncTaskLoadImage.onPostExecute(SearchListAdapter.java:140)
    at com.morlunk.mumbleclient.app.SearchListAdapter$AsyncTaskLoadImage.onPostExecute(SearchListAdapter.java:115)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and the lines that error occurs in them are :

```
circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader (bitmap,  Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

It's so weird because sometimes error occurs at the first line and sometimes it occurs at the second line and sometimes there is no force stop.
so does anyone knows how can I fix this?

Comment: Why so much code for just image loading ? Use Glide for image loading. It handles everything for you and is just one line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to set server image in Imageview using Library,

Like the following code:

```
Picasso
  .with(context)
  .load(url)
  .placeholder(placeHolderDrawable)
  .error(errorDrawable)
  .transform(circleTransform)
  .into(imageView);
```

and the code for the `circleTransform` copied from this link: https://gist.github.com/julianshen/5829333

```
public class CircleTransform implements Transformation {
    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float r = size/2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "circle";
    }
}
```

Comment: when I'm trying to compile Picasso or Glide to my project in gradle I'm getting these errors :
    /Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
    /Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1
    /Failed to resolve: annotationProcessor

Comment: which  buildToolsVersion you use

Comment: do  compileSdkVersion = 26
      supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"

Comment: I'm using buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"

Comment: change it and try with buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

Comment: changed but still got that issue

Comment: so update your build tools version and support library version same or update or downgrade....maybe it can happen because version is mismatch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182630/discussion-between-mayur-karmur-and-shakib-karami).